# How to load data from Apache nifi to GraphDB

Tags: apache-nifi, graphdb

How we can load data from Apache nifi to GraphDB. I am not able to find any reference videos and content regarding loading data from Apache nifi to GraphDB.
I wanted to know how we can integrate Apache nifi to GraphDB for loading the data.

Comment: there is not built in functionality in nifi. as for me you should look at GraphDB nalive options to import data. for example there is a `importrdf` commandline tool  https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.1/loading-data-using-importrdf.html

so, on the level of nifi you have to prepare data for import and then call a commandline tool

Comment: Not sure if the NAR is included with the convenience binary but we do have components for graph DB support including ExecuteGraphQueryRecord.

Comment: Actually I am having one data file that I need to load through Apache nifi to GraphDB. For that which processor I can use and also from GraphDB side what things I need to lookout. That I am not able to find out if you guys help me out for this.